# Reordering a collection what am I doing wrong?

Tags: c#, linq-to-objects

I need to reorder a collection
The final results should be that all the items in the collections that have propertyOne > 0 and PropertyTwo=0 should
be first and then the others should follow

I have done the following but I am not sure why it does not work!

```
IOrderedEnumerable<OrderLineItem> orderedItemList= 

OrderList.Cast<OrderLineItem>()
      .OrderBy(x => x.PropertyOne > 0)
      .ThenBy(x => x.PropertyTwo == 0);
```

Any Suggestions?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You're [ordering](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534966.aspx) your collection by comparing what your lambdas return, i.e. boolean values. `true` [is greater than](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wz786x34.aspx) `false`. Therefore, you need to either use [OrderByDescending()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534855.aspx):

```
var orderedItems
    = OrderList.Cast<OrderLineItem>()
               .OrderByDescending(x => x.PropertyOne > 0)
               .ThenByDescending(x => x.PropertyTwo == 0);
```

Or invert your predicates:

```
var orderedItems
    = OrderList.Cast<OrderLineItem>()
               .OrderBy(x => x.PropertyOne <= 0)
               .ThenBy(x => x.PropertyTwo != 0);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var orderedList = OrderList.Cast<OrderLineItem>()
      .OrderBy(x => x.PropertyOne > 0)
      .ThenBy(x=> x.PropertyTwo == 0);
```

Need to compare not assign the "ThenBy"

Answer (score 0):

You should use == not = in ThenBy

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

```
IOrderedEnumerable<OrderLineItem> orderedItemList= 

OrderList.Cast<OrderLineItem>()
      .OrderBy(x => (x.PropertyOne > 0 && x.PropertyTwo == 0) ? 0 : 1);
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for something like this?

```
IOrderedEnumerable<OrderLineItem> orderedItemList=     
OrderList.Cast<OrderLineItem>()
      .OrderBy(x => (x.PropertyOne > 0 && x.PropertyTwo == 0) ? 0 : 1);
```

This will put those where both criteria are true first, and all others after. If I'm misinterpreting your specification, please disregard.